# Reopen question

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Please, reopen question on "regionism". I improved it.

Professor Katie Wales, Chair of Modern English Language, School of English, University of Leeds invented the word.

> "The media regularly and aggressively promote such loaded oppositions
>   (e.g. Capitalist v. Communist) and they have done the most to promote
>   the idea of a North-South divide. So, by analogy with terms like
>   sexism and racism, bias against gender and race, I shall propose
>   regionism, bias against a region".

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be too late, as it seems to have been deleted.  But before asking for re-opening, consider (as with any *Is it a word?* question) - what answer do you want?  It is a word in the sense that it has been used (with a definition) in an academic paper: it is not a word in the sense that it is not in any dictionary; whether it does become a word depends on whether it is found useful by English speakers in the future.  None of these have anything to do with EL&U.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english

Comment: "None of these have anything to do with EL&U" - well not -nothing-. It's just a vague judgement, difficult to answer, Not Constructive.

Comment: @Mitch: actually, I meant 'nothing'.  OPs citation above answers the first question, so there's nothing further for us: he already knows it's not widely used, so nothing there; and whether it will be taken up in the future cannot be answered even by the moderators (unless, of course, you know different).  I suspect that behind this there is something like *What can I do to spread this useful neologism?*, which would be a question, though way off topic; at present, it's not even that.  (PS nothing personal intended; just that I think there are too many of these pseudoquestions).

Comment: My point is that of course this has -something- to do with language and usage in English, what the acceptance method of neologisms in English is. That's all. In total agreement otherwise.